# codeigniter form validation if failed send user back

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have this controller(visits.php) that use 3 models to build page,  then it pass 4 vars to a view.

this view contain a form that submit to another page (add_user.php)

my question is how can i send the user back to visits.php in case the for_validation is false ?
do i have to reload visits.php allover again ?-waste of resourss- or i should just send him back in history with js or php header for example ? can u plz show me an example of how u best handle false result of form_validation ?

Note that when i user

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

i couldnt echo validation_error() :(

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store validation_error() in a piece of flash data, then you can use header(Location) - or you could use the codeigniter redirect() function and fetch the flashdata in the redirected page.

Comment: Codeigniter has this functionality built in, why would you load the errors into flashdata and use header to redirect, makes no sense and isn't saving any resources over reloading the page in the controller.